# Custom item in inventory / custom tellraw

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm running a SMP server, and I want to add a ticketing functionality. I have a villager that sells a "ticket" (paper w/custom name). Is there a way so that when the player walks through a doorway entrance, it triggers a tellraw message, and on onclick the item is removed from their inventory and a scoreboard value is incremented? The logic seems simple enough, but I don't want it accidentally mixing things up if 2 players try to go through at the same time.

Ie. Players without the ticket gets tp'd back a block with a "Hey, you need a ticket!" sort of message.

Players with a ticket get a "Use your ticket? [Yes]" sort of message, which triggers a /trigger command on onclick

Or is there maybe a way to:

```
/scoreboard players set @a[carrying "ticket" in their inventory] promptRedeemTicket 1
```

or something like that?